# Can't open -CAfile for reading, No such file or directory (using openssl)

Tags: openssl

I am running the below command on Ubuntu 18.10:

```
ls -la /home/user/tmp/
drwxr-xr-x  2 user user      4096 Jun  6 14:11 .
drwxr-xr-x 38 user user      4096 Jun  6 09:31 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user      3158 Jun  6 13:48 ca.crt
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user      1952 Jun  6 13:49 server.crt
SERVER_CRT=/home/user/tmp/server.crt
CA_CRT=/home/user/tmp/ca.crt
openssl verify $SERVER_CRT -CAfile $CA_CRT
```

but get:

```
...
error 20 at 0 depth lookup: unable to get local issuer certificate
error /home/user/tmp/server.crt: verification failed
Can't open -CAfile for reading, No such file or directory
139708683215936:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:72:fopen('-CAfile','r')
139708683215936:error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:79:
unable to load certificate
...
error 18 at 0 depth lookup: self signed certificate
error /home/user/tmp/ca.crt: verification failed
```

But the two files indeed exist so why the `no such file` error?

Comment: **Put options** (with their arguments if any) **_before_** cert-filenames (or in general nonoption arguments): `openssl verify -CAfile $CA_CRT $SERVER_CRT`